# Multi line google charts from mysql database

Tags: php, charts

I'm having a problem regarding a chart i must use.
This is my query;

```
    SELECT e.Escola,  
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 5, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao5,
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 4, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao4,
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 3, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao3,
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 2, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao2,
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 1, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao1,
    COUNT(IF( a.Adequacao= 0, a.Adequacao, NULL)) AS Adequacao0,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 5, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao5,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 4, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao4,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 3, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao3,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 2, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao2,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 1, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao1,
    COUNT(IF( a.Participacao= 0, a.Participacao, NULL)) AS Participacao0,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 5, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao5,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 4, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao4,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 3, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao3,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 2, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao2,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 1, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao1,
    COUNT(IF( a.Consecucao= 0, a.Consecucao, NULL)) AS Consecucao0,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 5, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade5,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 4, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade4,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 3, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade3,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 2, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade2,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 1, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade1,
    COUNT(IF( a.Disponibilidade= 0, a.Disponibilidade, NULL)) AS Disponibilidade0
FROM atividades AS a
INNER JOIN escolas AS e ON (a.idEscola = e.idEscola) 
INNER JOIN anosescolares AS ae ON (a.idAnoEscolar = ae.idAnoEscolar)
WHERE ae.Estado = 1
GROUP BY e.Escola
```

So i have3 series, and i want to use a line chart,
I can't manage to get it working
Anyone has an example with 3 series?
 i have this error
All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Thanks

Comment: Check this one: https://jsfiddle.net/Lam58zjf/ you can use JS inside a PHP loop

Comment: it says page not exist

Comment: check my updated comment